# Merge data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a couple different data sets i am trying to visualize. First I have a list of all the bike share stations with lat/long and a station code. Second i have trip data that has the station code. I am hoping to pull the lat/long into the trip file. Basically i want to populate new lat/long columns in trip data by matching station codes.

Is there a simple way to do this in python?

[image: List of Stations]

[image: list of trips]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You mention dataframes in the tags, I assume you're using pandas? Share your code and explain where you got stuck. Also, please include examples of the actual data, instead of images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Is this the latitude and longitude of the trip made? SO how far between the two stations? And is it possible to get this data in a file I can use to test it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.